# Problems handling the scrolling of the webpage with javascript moving an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a little help: here is the piece of code incriminated:

html:

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="background-image background-cover"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inside blur-big background-cover"></div>
    <div class="inside blur-small background-cover"></div>
    <div class="inside clear background-cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.contain {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -98px;
  width: 150%;
}

.background-cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle .inside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
}

.blur-big {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
}

/* positioned slightly 'inside' the big blur */

.blur-small {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.clear {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 95px;
  width: 95px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {

} else
  addContainMouseMoveFunctionality(); //just add this functionality when it'll be used


function addContainMouseMoveFunctionality() {

  //do as little as possible in the mousemove-event, so initiate variables here
  let circle = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0];
  let contain = document.getElementsByClassName('contain')[0];

  //add event listener for the mouse enters the image, show circle
  contain.addEventListener("mousemove", moveCircle);

  //add event listener for when the mouse leaves the image, hide circle
  contain.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {

    //give the circle a position outside the viewport
    circle.style.top = '-999px';
    circle.style.left = '-999px';

  });

  function moveCircle(e) {

    //get the offset from the top to avoid the circle going all over the place when scrolling down or horizontally
    let doc = document.documentElement;
    let left = window.pageXOffset - doc.scrollLeft + doc.clientLeft;
    let top = window.pageYOffset - doc.scrollTop + doc.clientTop;

    //give the circle a position near the mouse, position minus half of its width/height to center it
    circle.style.top = top + e.pageY - circle.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
    circle.style.left = left + e.pageX - circle.offsetWidth / 2 + 98 + 'px'; // 98 is for the margin of contain
  }
}
```

I think the problem is with these formulas but maybe not:

```
circle.style.top = top + e.clientY - circle.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
circle.style.left = left + e.clientX - circle.offsetWidth / 2 + 98 + 'px';
```

Here is a fiddle which shows how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/hw615quf/7/https://jsfiddle.net/hw615quf/7/

When you scroll a little to the right, you will see what the problem is: the circle which was centred around the cursor is now no more centred...
It is not that problematic in this fiddle but when I incorporate my code on the Wordpress site with Salient, the circle is pretty much down and left from the cursor's position. When I scroll down, the circle is a little bit closer to the image but still not centred... And anyway, I don't want my circle to be centred only when the image is barely visible.

Maybe it is my formula which is problematic? Can anyone help me with this scroll?

Thanks for your help and for reading, have a nice day/evening/night :)

Benjamin

Comment: Please include all relevant code *in* the question, itself. Outside links can "go bad", making the question not useful for other users. Stack Overflow is a Q&A repository, not a help-desk. Content needs to be useful for "everyone". It would also help for you to include a screen shot of the problem. You can use the [edit] link under the question to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clientX` and `clientY` does not change as page scroll changes they remain fixed.  You should use `pageX` and `pageY` in this scenario. Like this

```
circle.style.top = top + e.pageY - circle.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
circle.style.left = left + e.pageX - circle.offsetWidth / 2 + 98 + 'px';
```

Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/681Lakn0/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

I have another problem with the same code: using pageX is ok but using pageY, my element is set ~1700px down the cursor which is definitely not what I'd want... Thus, my circle is not appearing in the viewport... Do you have an idea of what causes the problem?